# Use find result without ./

Tags: find

I'm trying to use find to create a bunch of symlinks but using the result with {} includes ./ before each filename. How can I avoid that?

```
find . -type l -name '*.h' -exec ln -s /sourcedir/{} /destinationdir/{} \;
```

Comment: Is your `find` supporting the `-printf` option?

Comment: yes i think it does

Comment: See the `find . -type l -name '*.h' -printf 'ln -s /sourcedir/%f /destinationdir/%f\n'`'s output. If you like it, pipe it to `sh`. Of course, special characters in the file names will be a problem.

Comment: @manatwork I think you have the best answer there. If you post it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: @manatwork, ITYW `%P` instead of `%f` here.

Comment: If all the relevant files (type l, name *.h) reside under /sourcedir/ then use `find sourcedir -type l -name '*.h' -exec ln -s {} /destinationdir/{} \;` ... You would run the find command from the parent of /sourcedir, which is the root.  On second thought that won't work because it will try to create a link called /destinationdir/sourcedir/file.h

Answer (score 24):

You only have to change one character in your command:

```
find * -type l -name '*.h' -exec ln -s /sourcedir/{} /destinationdir/{} \;
#    ^
```

Comment: Good point, but it should be noted though that it would fail if any file is named `!`, `(` or `)` or anything starting with a `-` in the current directory. It will also skip the hidden files and dirs in the current directory.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas You are right. I had thought about the hidden files and dirs myself but found only one such file in the 75K `.h` on my systems (ubuntu Linux).

Comment: If I `find` stuff in another directory (eg. `find src/ -type l`), is there a way to exclude `src/` from the results?

Comment: I don't understand why you would not do `cd src; find * -type l` in that case.

Answer (score 7):

Use the standard syntax, like:

```
S=/sourcedir D=/destdir find . -type l -name '*.h' -exec sh -c '
  for i do
    ln -s -- "$S${i#.}" "$D/$i"
  done' sh {} +
```

If you want to use GNUisms, you could do:

```
find . -type l -name '*.h' -printf '/sourcedir/%P\0/destdir/%P\0' |
  xargs -r0n2 ln -s
```

Or if `/sourcedir` *is* the current directory:

```
find "$PWD" -type l -name '*.h' -printf '%p\0/destdir/%P\0' |
  xargs -r0n2 ln -s
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` will print names relative to the paths you provide as arguments. In this case, the path is `.`, so all the names will begin with `./`. To get absolute paths, you need to provide an absolute path as input:

```
find "$PWD" -type l -name '*.h'
```

This command uses the `$PWD` environment variable, which contains the absolute path of the current working directory, so it should preserve the meaning of your original command.

Comment: He would then need to strip that `$PWD` off the destination of the `ln` command.

Comment: good point. Also I think I was answering a question he didn't ask. :(

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
find . -type l -name '*.h' -print0 | cut -z -c3- \
    | xargs -0 -I '{}' ln -s '/sourcedir/{}' '/destinationdir/{}'
```

[`man find`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)

- `-print0` print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a `null`
  character.

[`man cut`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) - remove sections from each line of files

- `-z` line delimiter is `NUL`, not newline.
- `-c` select only these characters.
- `N-` from N'th byte, character or field, counted from 1, to end of line.

[`man xargs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) - build and execute command lines from standard input.

- `xargs [options] [command [initial-arguments]]`
- `-0` Input items are terminated by a `null` character instead of by whitespace,
  and the quotes and backslash are not special (every character is taken
  literally).
- `-I replace-str`
  Replace occurrences of `replace-str` in the `initial-arguments` with
  names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate
  input items; instead the separator is the newline character.
  Implies `-L 1`.
- `-L max-lines`
  Use at most `max-lines` nonblank input lines per command line.